# Convert day of month into Unixtime with millisecond accuracy in OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I'd like to use Bash user input to enter year, month, day, hour to create a unixtimestamp with millisecond accuracy - Please provide help with the date command for MACOSX10.9

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
read -e -p "year? " year
read -e -p "month? " month
read -e -p "day? " day
read -e -p "hour? " hour
echo date ......
```

example number of digits to millisecond accuracy 1417502014450

The output is to be used to create a filter, not a discovery of the current system time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is UTC, the answer is

```
echo $(( $(date -jf '%F %T %z' "$year-$month-$day $hour:00:00 +0000" +%s) * 1000 ))
```

Timezone input AND date arithmetic could be used to ensure that the %z equals +0000 to give a correct unixtimestamp for use as a filter or test against the applications system time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timestamp (in seconds) with:

```
date -jf '%F %T' "$year-$month-$day $hour:00:00" +%s
```

Milliseconds are, as far as I can see, not supported, but you can always multiply by 1000.

```
echo $(( $(date -jf '%F %T' "$year-$month-$day $hour:00:00" +%s) * 1000 ))
```

Note that this command is *not* portable to GNU date (ie. Linux).

See:
[`date(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html)
[`strftime(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strftime)

Comment: why does the value keep on changing?

Comment: @user2314105 It would appear that if the number of minutes/seconds isn't given, it will take the current amount of minutes/seconds (as apposed to just setting it to 0); you can prevent this by explicitly specifying the amount of minutes or seconds (as a variable, or just as 00)

Comment: @user2314105 Thank you for the edit (I improved it slightly), but the minute and second don't *have* to be specified; both ways of doing things are "sane", and the "correct" one depends on what you want to do :-)

Comment: Still apparently incorrect - The result is not UnixTime as it has taken the local time off the machine, not UTC input - the difference may need to be calculated as no usable hint in the man page? test with date -r <result>

Comment: @user2314105 You can try adding a time zone; You can use `%z` & `+0100` (for example); you can get the system's timezone with `date +%z`.

Comment: echo $(( $(date -jf '%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S %z' "2014-12-02 09 00 00 +1100" +%s) * 1000 )) doesn't change the incorrect output

Comment: @sim I've created a stackoverflow problem - An edit (warning to future viewers) on the answer has been approved, but is incorrect. The correct warning text edit has been rejected. should be "input must be adjusted to UTC to get a correct UnixTimestamp, otherwise it is your system time" - could you please edit your answer to warn others?

Comment: @user2314105 I don't see what's not working? by default, `date` uses the system's timestamp; if you want to use UTC, add `%z` and explicitly set it to `+0000`; this is exactly the same behaviour as with the "missing" minutes/seconds... You should edit your question with more details about what output you do want with which input.

Comment: My assumption with the question was the 'creation' of a unixtimestamp to use elsewhere (eg as a filter). Your assumption is that the application wants to use the current system timestamp. Edits to be made to question and answer for the benefit of future readers - your answer lead to this understanding, so thanks